# Mathematica: help solving a system of non-linear equations with inequality constraints

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a system of 4 non-linear equations in 4 unknowns. In addition I have 1 inequality constraint that I need a function of the four unknowns to satisfy (and then I need the four unknowns to be non-negative). My problem has 12 or so parameters and I intend to eventually solve the problem for a range of parameters to see how the solution behaves. Not all parameters included in the code below are used in this particular setup (they are used in others). I understand that my system may not have a solution for all parameter values and that I will need to do some work to find the parameter space which works but before I do that I need to know how to solve a system of non-linear equations with inequality constraint. I am new to mathematica and I am including my code below. In the code I first give some parameter values, then I define some coefficients and then I write the 4 equations and 1 inequality inside the FindInstance function (which doesn't work). I have solved these 4 equations for a particular set of parameters with the FindRoot function but I got a solution that didn't satisfy the inequality. Thanks alot. The code in mathematica is below:

```
    values = {{r, \[Delta], \[Sigma], Subscript[i, e], Subscript[i, u], 
    Subscript[\[Lambda], e ], Subscript[\[Lambda], u  ], Subscript[H, 
    0], Subscript[C, f] , F, \[Tau], Subscript[C, Ren]}, {0.047, 0.05,
    0.1632, 5, 0, 0.005, 0.02, 100, 17, 80, 0.3, 8}};
    G = Grid[values, 
    Dividers -> {{None, None, None}, {{Blue}, {Blue}, None}}];
    r = values[[2, 1]];
    \[Delta] = values[[2, 2]];
    \[Sigma] = values[[2, 3]];
    Subscript[i, e] = values[[2, 4]];
    Subscript[i, u] = values[[2, 5]];
    Subscript[\[Lambda], e] = values[[2, 6]];
    Subscript[\[Lambda], u] = values[[2, 7]];
    Subscript[H, 0] = values[[2, 8]];
    Subscript[C, f] = values[[2, 9]];
    F = values[[2, 10]];
    \[Tau] = values[[2, 11]];
    Subscript[C, Ren] = values[[2, 12]];
    Subscript[I, e] = 
    Subscript[i, e]/
    r - (Subscript[i, e] - Subscript[i, u]) Subscript[\[Lambda], 
    e]/(r (r + Subscript[\[Lambda], e] + Subscript[\[Lambda], u]));
    Subscript[I, u] = 
    Subscript[i, u]/
    r + (Subscript[i, e] - Subscript[i, u]) Subscript[\[Lambda], 
    u]/(r (r + Subscript[\[Lambda], e] + Subscript[\[Lambda], u]));
    Solve[k (k - 1) + 2 (r - \[Delta])/\[Sigma]^2 k - 2 r/\[Sigma]^2 == 0,
    k];
    {Subscript[k, 1 ], Subscript[k, 2 ]} = k /. % ;
    Clear[k];
    Subscript[k, 1]
    Subscript[k, 2]
    L1 = (H1S^(-Subscript[k, 1])* (F - (c1*F)/r + (
    H1S^(Subscript[k, 2])*((F* H1D^(Subscript[k, 1])* (-c1 + r))/r +
      H1S^(Subscript[k, 1])*(-(c0* F)/r + (c1*F)/
        r + (H1D^(Subscript[k, 
            2])*(-F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* (c0 - r) + 
            H0S^(Subscript[k, 1])* (c0*F - H0D *r + 
               r* Subscript[C, f])))/((H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])* 
            H0S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
           H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))*
         r) + (H1D^(Subscript[k, 
            1])*(F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*(c0 - r) - 
            H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])* (c0*F - H0D* r + 
               r* Subscript[C, f])))/((H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])* 
            H0S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
           H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))*r) + 
        Subscript[C, Ren])))/(
    H1D^(Subscript[k, 2])* H1S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
    H1D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H1S^(Subscript[k, 2]))));
    M1 = (((F* H1D^(Subscript[k, 1])* (-c1 + r))/r + 
    H1S^(Subscript[k, 1])*(-(c0* F)/r + (c1*F)/
    r + (H1D^(Subscript[k, 
        2])*(-F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* (c0 - r) + 
        H0S^(Subscript[k, 1])* (c0*F - H0D *r + 
           r* Subscript[C, f])))/((H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])* 
        H0S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
       H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))*
     r) + (H1D^(Subscript[k, 
        1])*(F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*(c0 - r) - 
        H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])* (c0*F - H0D* r + 
           r* Subscript[C, f])))/((H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])* 
        H0S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
       H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))*r) + 
    Subscript[C, Ren]))/(
    H1D^(Subscript[k, 2])* H1S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
    H1D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H1S^(Subscript[k, 2])));
    L0 = ((-F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*(c0 - r) + 
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])*(c0*F - H0D*r + 
    r*Subscript[C, f]))/((H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
    H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))* r));
    M0 = ((-F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])*(c0 - r) + 
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 1])*(c0*F - H0D*r + 
    r*Subscript[C, f]))/((H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - 
    H0D^(Subscript[k, 1])* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))* r));
    c0 = ((-F*H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*r*Subscript[k, 1] + 
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])*
    r*(-H0D + (H0D + Subscript[C, f])*Subscript[k, 1]))/(
    F*(H0D^(Subscript[k, 2]) - H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))*(-1 + \[Tau])*
    Subscript[k, 1]));
    c1 = (H1D^(Subscript[k, 1])*H1S^(Subscript[k, 1])*
    r*(-1* F*H1S^(-Subscript[k, 1]) + 
    H1D^(-Subscript[k, 1]) *Subscript[C, Ren] + (
    F*H1D^(-Subscript[k, 1])* (1 - \[Tau])*(-80*
     H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])*Subscript[k, 1] + 
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 
       2])*(- H0D + (15 + H0D)* Subscript[k, 1])))/((-56*
     H0D^(Subscript[k, 2]) + 56*H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))*Subscript[
    k, 1]) + (
    F*H0S^(-Subscript[k, 
     1])*(r + ((1 - \[Tau])* (-80* H0D^(Subscript[k, 2])* r* 
        Subscript[k, 1] + 
       H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])* 
        r* (-H0D + (15 + H0D)*Subscript[k, 1])))/((-56* 
        H0D^(Subscript[k, 2]) + 56* H0S^(Subscript[k, 2]))* 
     Subscript[k, 1])))/r))/(
    F *(H1S^(Subscript[k, 1]) - H1D^(Subscript[k, 1]))*(1 - \[Tau]));
    A1 = (F*H1S^(-Subscript[k, 1])*(r + c1*(-1 + \[Tau]))*Subscript[k, 
    2])/(r *(Subscript[k, 1] - Subscript[k, 2]));
    B1 = (F*H1S^(-Subscript[k, 2])*(r + c1*(-1 + \[Tau]))*Subscript[k, 
    1])/(r *(Subscript[k, 2] - Subscript[k, 1]));

    FindInstance[
    L1*Subscript[H, 0]^(Subscript[k, 1]) + 
    M1*Subscript[H, 0]^Subscript[k, 2] + c1*F/r == F &&  
    L0*H1D^(Subscript[k, 1]) + M0*H1D^Subscript[k, 2] + c0*F/r - 
    Subscript[C, Ren] == 
    H1D - Subscript[C, 
    f] && (F*H0S^(-Subscript[k, 1])*(r + c0*(-1 + \[Tau]))* Subscript[
    k, 2]) == (H0D^(-Subscript[k, 1])*(-H0D*
    r + (H0D*r + c0*F *(-1 + \[Tau]) + r* Subscript[C, f])* 
    Subscript[k, 2])) && (F*
    H1S^(-Subscript[k, 2])*(r + c1*(-1 + \[Tau]))*Subscript[k, 
    1]) == (H0S^(-Subscript[k, 2])* 
    H1D^(-Subscript[k, 2])*((-c0 + c1)*F*
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])*(-1 + \[Tau]) + 
    F*H1D^(Subscript[k, 2])* (c0 + r - c0 *\[Tau]) + 
    H0S^(Subscript[k, 2])* r* Subscript[C, Ren])* Subscript[k, 
    1]) &&  A1*(Subscript[H, 0])^(Subscript[k, 1]) + 
    B1*(Subscript[H, 0])^(Subscript[k, 2]) + (H1S) - (1 - \[Tau])*c1*
    F/r >  0 && H1S > 0 && H0S > 0 && H1D > 0 && H0D > 0, {H1S, H0S, 
    H1D, H0D}, Reals]
    Clear[c0, c1, L0, L1, M0, M1, H1D, H0D, H1S, H0S]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Questions & Answers and not a code review site. I suggest trying to reduce your code to a minimum and then formulate a question that helps you identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the code in case anybody wanted to look at the actual equations I was looking to solve. I don't have a code problem per se. I just don't know the right built-in mathematica function to use to solve a system of nonlinear equations and inequations.

Comment: @Amayta The problem is that there is not only one, but a whole bunch. And each of them with many, many options available. So if you can post a short example of the _kind_ of equations you are not able to solve, we may help better. Otherwise a good but general answer such as the one already posted by @Jason is the best you may get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can use `FindRoot` with constraints (inequalities, etc.).  For non-linear constrained optimization you are going to want to investigate the following built in functions

- Maximize[...]
- NMaximize[...]
- FindMaximum[...]
- Minimize[...]
- NMinimize[...]
- FindMinimum[...]

I'm not sure which one you would want for this particular problem.

Here is an example of Maximize in action:

```
Maximize[{(2 x + y - z)/(5 x - 7 y + 3), 
  0 <= x + y + z <= 1 && 1 <= x - y + z <= 2 && x - y - z == 3}, {x, 
  y, z}]
```

which gives the following output:

```
{5/13, {x -> 2, y -> 0, z -> -1}}
```

More information on constrained optimization in Mathematica (including the non-linear variety) can be found at the following links:

- http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/ConstrainedOptimization/ConstrainedOptimization.pdf
- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your response. I can formulate the problem as a constrained optimization.